# Dealing with case sensitive name collisions in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, wsdl, collision, case-sensitive

I'm consuming a 3rd party web service in a .Net (3.5) project (imported via "Service References") and unfortunately in their wisdom they've created an enum that has case sensitive name collisions, eg.

```cs
// This is the C# generated from the wsdl
public enum SIunitType {
  // snip
  l,
  Nm,
  rpm,
  m3,
  L,
  // snip
}

// Pre populate a pair of enums so that we can easily query them in VB
public class Class1 {
  public static SIunitType small_l = SIunitType.l;
  public static SIunitType big_l = SIunitType.L;
}
```

```vb
  ' VB method
  public class Class1 {
    Public Shared Sub Foo()
      Dim i1 As Integer = CInt(Class1.small_l) ' This gives 10
      Dim i2 As Integer = CInt(Class1.big_l) ' This gives 18
      Dim b As Boolean = (Class1.small_l = Class1.big_l) ' This is false

      Dim isBig As Boolean
      Select Case Class1.big_l
        Case SIunitType.l
          ' Never get here
          isBig = False

        Case CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(SIunitType), "L", False), SIunitType)
          ' So, parsing the case sensitive value works, is this the only way?
          isBig = True

      End Select
    End Sub
```

As you can see, there as to "l"s. This is fine if we're using C# or any other case sensitive language. However, when the library is imported into a VB.net project we quite obviously get some problems:
The intellisense corrected the "L" to an "l", probably as it's defined first.
When debugging, querying a enum value returned by the library shows that there is a difference, however there's not way to test it, apart from using magic numbers (which defeats the purpose of using an enum), or reflection.

A couple of points:

- The obvious answer is "don't use names that can cause this issue, however **I don't** have that option - it's a 3rd party.
- Getting the 3rd party to change this isn't going to happen - this is a web service provided to companies across Europe.
- Unfortunately I'm stuck using VB.Net for part of the project, so "use a *better* language" isn't an option.

So, can anyone suggest a better of way dealing with this?

Comment: I don't see any other options other than the 2 you've already come up with (magic numbers or reflection).

Comment: You could create your own enum with the same values and cast it. An enum if just storing a number.  Dim v As SIunitType = CType(SIunitType.BigL, SIunitType)

Comment: Thanks Dave & the_lotus for the feedback.
@the_lotus: While it's an idea, I'm not massively keen on duplicating the enum as it leaves us open to errors if the webservice is updated.
Any suggestions what I should do with the question?

Comment: @oobayly personally I think there's no pretty solution but I'm not one of the pro in here.

Comment: Same problem applies to the PayPal web api, they have both `Y` and `y` in an enum. Luckily the two values mean the same and it's not difficult to fix the generated service mapping file by deleting one of them.